# Two unix processes write on the same TCP socket in the same time

Tags: sockets, process, multiprocessing, read-write, tcpsocket

Can two unix processes write on TCP sockets (that is there is a way by witch the OS can schedule writing done by each process) ?
If so, what problems could appen?

Comment: Yes. The meaning of the part in parentheses eludes me. Writes and sends are atomic, but the sends by each process can be arbitrarily interleaved.

Answer (score 2):

Well... yes... two unix processes can `write` to a single (shared) TCP socket ... but I would consider this a design flaw.

`write` might be atomic, but it can be partial, causing interleaved data to be written between `write` calls.

An application level syncing element will be required to circumvent this issue.

In all likelihood, this adds complexity without adding value.